# Is homotopy group of infinite product of spaces a direct sum or a direct product of groups?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-topology, category-theory, direct-sum, direct-product

The title pretty much says it all. Do I have $\pi_n(\Pi_{i=1}^\infty X_i)\cong \bigoplus\limits_{i=1}^\infty \pi_n(X_i)$ or $\pi_n(\Pi_{i=1}^\infty X_i)\cong \Pi_{i=1}^\infty \pi_n(X_i)$?

From what I see in a specific example, it seems that direct sum is right.

Whatever the answer is, I would really like to understand whether there is some sort of categorical (or any other) explanation to it. Intuition tells me that covariant functor $\pi_n$ must map product to product, but I am not $100$% sure whether it is generally true.

Thank you.

Comment: Your two paragraphs seem to contradict each other.

Comment: What do maps into a product look like?

Comment: The unhelpful answer to the question in the title is "yes".

Comment: Do you know the universal property of the *product* in category theory?

Comment: @Berci They do not. One is telling that my intuition votes for the product, the other is telling that example in the book behaves like it should be direct sum.

Comment: @PaulFrost Yes, I do. Not sure how it helps here though

Comment: @Thorgott More or less like a collection of maps to each factor. How does it help to answer the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We shall show that for any index set $A$ there is a natural bijection

$$i  : \pi_n(\prod_{\alpha \in A}X_\alpha) \to \prod_{\alpha \in A}\pi_n(X_\alpha) \tag{1} .$$
$\pi_n(Y) = \pi_n(Y,y_0)$ is the set of pointed homotopy classes $[f]$ of pointed maps $f : (S^n,*) \to (Y,y_0)$. For $n = 0$ this a just a set with a basepoint, for $n = 1$ it has a natural structure of a group, for $n> 1$ a natural structure of a abelian group.

The expression $\oplus_{\alpha \in A}G_\alpha$ only makes sense for abelian groups $G_\alpha$, and it would be weird if you would not have an isomorphism for $n = 0 ,1$ because of the lack of an appropriate object.

Let us define
$$i : \pi_n(\prod_{\alpha \in A}X_\alpha) \to \prod_{\alpha \in A}\pi_n(X_\alpha), i([f])  = ([p_\alpha \circ f])_{\alpha \in A} .$$
Here $p_\alpha : \prod_{\alpha \in A}X_\alpha \to X_\alpha$ denotes projection onto the factor with index $\alpha$.

This is clearly well-defined because if $f \simeq g$, then $p_\alpha \circ f \simeq p_\alpha \circ g$ for all $\alpha$. By the universal property of the product each family $(\phi_\alpha)$ of pointed maps $\phi_\alpha :(S^n,*)  \to (X_\alpha,x_\alpha)$ has the form $(\phi_\alpha) = (p_\alpha \circ f)$ for a unique pointed map $f : (S^n,*)  \to \prod_{\alpha \in A}(X_\alpha,x_\alpha)$, thus $i$ is surjective. To show that $i$ is also injective, note that if $p_\alpha \circ f \simeq p_\alpha \circ g$ for all $\alpha$, then we can choose pointed homotopies $h_n : (S^n,*) \times I \to (X_\alpha,x_\alpha)$ from $p_\alpha \circ f$ to $p_\alpha \circ g$.  Again by the universal property of the product we get a pointed homotopy $H :  (S^n,*) \times I \to  \prod_{\alpha \in A}(X_\alpha,x_\alpha)$ such that $p_\alpha \circ H = h_\alpha$ for all $\alpha$. By construction $H$ is a homotopy from $f$ to $g$. Therefore $i$ is a bijection for all $n$.

For $n > 0$ it remains to be shown that $i$ is a group homomorphism (and thus a group isomorphism). But this is clear because $([p_\alpha \circ f]) =((p_\alpha)_*([f]))$ and each $(p_\alpha)_* : \pi_n(\prod_{\alpha \in A}X_\alpha) \to \pi_n(X_\alpha)$ is a group homomorphism.